# Displaying two relationships to "self" in Admin portal via a Django ModelAdmin with Inlines

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In brief, i'm trying to get Django Admin to render inlines for more than one relationship to self. Can it be done? How? Take the following *untested* *illustration*; Assuming it worked i'd go to admin portal, select person, and add children (sons/daughters) and students.

**Model Example (models.py)**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self',related_name='children')
    teacher = models.ForeignKey('self',related_name='students')
```

**Django Admin (admin.py)**

```
class ChildrenInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Person
    fk_name = 'parent'

class StudentsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Person
    fk_name = 'teacher'

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inline = [ChildrenInline,StudentsInline]
    model = Person

admin.site.register(Person,PersonAdmin)
```

If the above code it technically correct i'll need to figure out what's going on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo !

`inline =` instead of plural `inlines =` like in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin).

I tested, it works with `inlines =` :)

Also, kudos for posting the right code to reproduce !